# com_create_guid() is not defined : returns fatal error

Tags: php, zend-framework

I am using PHP 5 on my dedicated linux server

> 5.2.6 (cli) (built: May  7 2008 01:11:22)  Copyright (c) 1997-2008 The
>   PHP Group Zend Engine v2.2.0,
>   Copyright (c) 1998-2008 Zend
>   Technologies

but com_create_guid function is not working to me it's returning this error message

> Fatal error: Call to undefined
>   function com_create_guid() in
>   /var/www/html/mysite/application/modules/consultant/models/Consultant.php
>   on line 34

I checked http://in.php.net/com_create_guid . It says you just need PHP5 (and i have that)
but this function not working :(

Answer (score 17, accepted):

COM functions are [only available on Windows](http://www.php.net/manual/en/com.requirements.php).

> COM functions are only available for
>   the Windows version of PHP.
>
> .Net support requires PHP 5 and the
>   .Net runtime.